# How to create a table with multiple columns with data from the same dictionary?

Tags: html, django, django-views, tags

I am trying to create a table with HTML tags but I am stuck with it.
I've tried to play with `{% for i in list %}`, but I couldn't find a solution.

```
list = {'ticker': tickers, 'price': prices}
```

---

```
   <tbody>

     <tr>
        {% for i in price %}
         <td>{{ i }}</td>
        {% endfor %}
        {% for i in ticker %}
         <td>{{ i }}</td>
        {% endfor %}

     </tr>
    <tr>

    </tr>
   </tbody>
```

I would see two columns one close to another, but I don't see any columns now.

Comment: Could you add some example data and a clear description of your desired result?

Comment: Hello, my goal is to create a table with 2 columns that contain 2 different variables from a list.

I created a dictionary with the two tags but I am not able to stream the variables in the table properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
<tbody>
   {% for i in list %}
      <tr>
          <td>{{ i.ticker }}</td>
          <td>{{ i.price }}</td>
      </tr>
   {% endfor %}
  </tbody>
```

for more details refer [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/templates/)

hope it helps

Comment: I had to re-do the list that is parsing the data to the dictionary to make it work. Thanks a lot!